# Fluent assertion to verify DateTime field is not empty

Tags: fluent-assertions

```
var dte = "2021-12-18T15:06:33.2677927Z"
dte.Should().
```

I want to check that this dte is not empty.

Currently I am using :

```
dte.Should().BeAfter(new DateTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example, your definition of an "empty" `DateTime` seems to be one different from the default value.

If you're looking for a more readable/idiomatic way to express that, I would go with

```cs
DateTime subject = MethodUnderTest();
subject.Should().NotBe(default);
```

For the general case, one cannot speak of an "empty" `DateTime` since even the default value is just the minimum representable valid datetime, namely `0001-01-01T00:00:00`.

So all of these are identical.

- `DateTime.Parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00")`
- `default(DateTime)`
- `new DateTime()`
- `DateTime.MinValue`
- `DateTime.FromBinary(0)`